# How do I compare 2 linked list elements with O(n) complexity? (Python)

Tags: python, nested, time-complexity, doubly-linked-list

I have to compare 2 double linked list elements which are names and add the names that are in both list to a new one. I have to do it with O(n) complexity and without using python lists, dictionaries, etc. I can only use linked lists or if needed piles or queues but nothing more.

Is it even posible to do it in O(n)? What first comes to my mind is a while into another while but i need O(n) and everything I try ends up with O(n^2) :(

Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: Are the lists sorted?

Comment: Yes, sorted by name. Also the new list has to be sorted.

Comment: You should put that in the question. I think that without a hash-table approach, it would be impossible without that assumption. With that assumption it seems to be reasonably straightforward. Have a single loop, where in each pass through the loop you look at the current elements of both lists, as well as the list you are building and decide what to do. If you have implemented merge-sort, this is similar to the merge part of merge-sort.